# Horde Authentication Backend Configuration

Tags: mysql, email, authentication, horde

I've installed Postfix, Postfixadmin, Dovecot and Horde successfully on Kubuntu 12.04.

When I go to mail.mydomain.com, it goes to the Horde dummy administration page.

When I tried to Add User, it says "Your authentication backend does not support adding users. If you wish to use Horde to administer user accounts, you must use a different authentication backend."

How can I use "Different authentication backend" ??

Answer (score 3):

The error you get means that you use a authentication backend which cannot write to users database.

Assuming you have updated to the latest Horde version (5.1.5), I suppose in your Horde config (`-> Administration/Configuration/Horde/Authentication`) you are using the default "IMP auth" backend (which normally uses IMAP backend), thus you cannot write/add users to IMAP backend.

If you want to add new users over Horde web-access config panel, you have to select an other authentication backend first - select (and configure) **SQL** or **LDAP** backends (in `Administration/Configuration/Horde/Authentication`), they support addding users (because you can write to these backends - you cannot write to IMAP).

Regards,
Megodin